# Only one JButton appears on GridLayout unless getRandom(); updateNumber(); are added after the for-loop in startGame()

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
```

> it is a simple summation math game. The sum is a random number within range 2 to 18. User needs to click 2 number buttons (1-9) to come up with this random sum.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    
    JFrame gameFrame; 
    JPanel gamePanelGeneral, gamePanelMiddle, gamePanelBottom;
    JButton startButton, endGame;
    JButton[]numberButtons = new JButton[9];
    JLabel welcome, gameRule, pointsCounter;
    JTextArea dataAnalysis;
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("logo.png");
    int min = 2;
    int max = 18;
    int num1,puzzleNumber;
    ArrayList<Integer> win = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> lose = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    class roundButton extends JButton {
        Color col = Color.yellow;
        public roundButton(String text){
               super(text);
                setContentAreaFilled(false);
              }
        
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
               g.setColor(this.col);
               g.fillOval(0, 0, getSize().width-1, getSize().height-1);
               super.paintComponent(g);
            }
    }
```

> the constructor makes a frame

```
    MyFrame(){
            gameFrame = new JFrame();
            gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            gameFrame.setTitle("Math Game");
            gameFrame.setIconImage(image.getImage());  
            gameFrame.setSize(500,500);
            gameFrame.setVisible(true);
            gameFrame.setLayout(null);
            
  
    }
```

> this is to make a button

```
    JButton gameButtons(int xPosition, int yPosition, int width, int height, String text, JPanel panel) {
        roundButton button = new roundButton(text);
        button.setBounds(xPosition, yPosition, width, height);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setFocusable(false);
        button.setBorder(null);
        panel.add(button);
        return button;
    }
```

> this is to make a label

```
    JLabel gameLabels(int xPosition, int yPosition, int width, int height, String text, JPanel panel) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        label.setBounds(xPosition, yPosition, width, height);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        panel.add(label);
        return label;
    }
```

> and this makes a panel

```
    JPanel gamePanels(int xPosition, int yPosition, int width, int height, JFrame frame) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(xPosition, yPosition, width, height);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.repaint();
        return panel;
    } 
    
    JTextArea gameTxArea(int xPosition, int yPosition, int width, int height, String text, JPanel panel) {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(xPosition, yPosition, width, height);
        textArea.setText(text);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setOpaque(false);
        panel.add(textArea);
        return textArea;
    }
```

> this just returns a random number

```
     int getRandom() {
         int x = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
         if(x == puzzleNumber) {
             x = getRandom();
         } else {
             puzzleNumber = x;
         }
         return puzzleNumber ;
     }
```

> this is the intro page (window) before the game starts

```
    void launchScreen() {
        gamePanelGeneral = gamePanels(0,0,500,500, gameFrame);
        welcome = gameLabels(150,50,300,50,"Welcome to mini math game!", gamePanelGeneral);
        startButton = gameButtons(180, 100, 100, 30,"Start", gamePanelGeneral);
        startButton.setBounds(180, 100, 100, 30);
    }
```

> this is the part where all happens the game works like it is supposed to be

```
    void startGame() {
        gameFrame.remove(gamePanelGeneral);
        gamePanelGeneral = gamePanels(0,0,500,60, gameFrame);
        gamePanelMiddle = gamePanels(120,80,250,250, gameFrame);
        gamePanelMiddle.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,10,10));
        gamePanelBottom = gamePanels(20,350,450,100, gameFrame);
        
        
        this.puzzleNumber = getRandom();
        
        gameRule = gameLabels(150,15,300,15, "Select two numbers that add up " + this.puzzleNumber, gamePanelGeneral);
        pointsCounter = gameLabels(200,40,200,15, "Win: " + win.size() + " " +  "Lose: " + lose.size(), gamePanelGeneral);
        endGame = gameButtons(180, 0, 100, 50,"End Game", gamePanelBottom);
    
        
        for(int i=0; i<numberButtons.length; i++) {
        
            numberButtons[i] = gameButtons(0, 0,45,30, String.valueOf(i+1), gamePanelMiddle);
        
        }
```

> here is the bit I can't figure out. When i run these 2 methods (getRandom() and updateNUmber()), there are 9 buttons populated on the grid. If they are excluded, only one button appears on the grid.

```
        getRandom();
        updateNumber();
    }
    
    void updateNumber() {
        gameRule.setText("Select two numbers that add up " + this.puzzleNumber);
        pointsCounter.setText("Win: " + win.size() + " " +  "Lose: " + lose.size());
    }
    
        
    double equal_above10(ArrayList<Integer>arrList, boolean b) {
        double accumulator = 0;
        
        if (b) {
            for (int i: arrList) {
                if(i >=10) {
                    accumulator++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int i: arrList) {
                if(i < 10) {
                    accumulator++;
                }
            }
        } return accumulator;
    }   
    
    String percentOfWin(ArrayList<Integer>arrList1, ArrayList<Integer>arrList2) {
        String printMessage = " ";
        double x = equal_above10(arrList1, true);
        double y = equal_above10(arrList2, true);
        double w = equal_above10(arrList1, false);
        double z = equal_above10(arrList2, false);
        
        if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
            
        } else {
            printMessage = "Percentage of win for numbers greater than or equal to 10: " 
            + Math.round((equal_above10(arrList1,true)/((equal_above10(arrList1,true)+(equal_above10(arrList2,true))))*100))
            + "\n";
        }
        
        if (w == 0 && z == 0) {
            return printMessage;
            
        } 
        else {
            printMessage += "Percentage of win for numbers less than 10: " 
                    + Math.round((equal_above10(arrList1,false)/((equal_above10(arrList1,false)+(equal_above10(arrList2,false))))*100)) 
                    +"\n";
        }
        
        
        return printMessage; 
    }
        
        
        void gameAnalysis() {
        gameFrame.remove(gamePanelGeneral);
        gameFrame.remove(gamePanelMiddle);
        gameFrame.remove(gamePanelBottom);
        gamePanelGeneral = gamePanels(0,0,500,500, gameFrame);
        dataAnalysis = gameTxArea(20,30,460,300,"Game Sessions Data Analyzed: \n \n"
                + "Numbers you got correct: " + win + "\n"
                + "Numbers you got wrong: " + lose + "\n"
                + percentOfWin(win, lose),  gamePanelGeneral);
        
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==startButton) {
            startGame();        
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<numberButtons.length;i++) {           
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[i]) { 
                if(num1 == 0) {
                    num1 = i+1;
                } else {
                    if (num1+i+1 == this.puzzleNumber) {
                        win.add(puzzleNumber);
                        }else {
                        lose.add(puzzleNumber);
                    }
                num1 = 0;
                puzzleNumber = getRandom();
                updateNumber();
                }           
            }   
        }
        
        if(e.getSource()==endGame) {
            gameAnalysis();     
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception{
      MyFrame mathGame = new MyFrame();
        mathGame.launchScreen();  
}
}
```

Comment: Don't use null layouts. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre].

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).